# JQGrid with EntityDataSource not getting column from related object

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, entitydatasource

JQGrid with EntityDataSource not getting column from related object

The field Number from the Phone table which is related by phoneid in VetCertifieds gives an error:The column with DataField=Phone.Number does not exist in the datasource.

Phone.Number works in a DataList.

Any Ideas?

```
  <cc1:JQGrid ID="Jqgrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" 
            ShrinkToFit="False">
            <Columns> 
                   <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="FirstName" >                       
                </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="MiddleName"  Visible="false">
                </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="LastName" >
                </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="Phone.Number" >
                </cc1:JQGridColumn>
                <cc1:JQGridColumn DataField="AddressID" >
                </cc1:JQGridColumn>


            </Columns>
        </cc1:JQGrid>

    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=VetPhoneBookContext" 
        DefaultContainerName="VetPhoneBookContext" 
        EntitySetName="VetCertifieds" Include="Phone,Address" EnableFlattening="False"
            >
     </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Comment: It seems be not a question about jqGrid which is open source **JavaScript** product (jQuery plugin). Compare the description of [jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid/info) tag with the description of [jqgrid-asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jqgrid-asp.net/info) tag for example.

Comment: Added that tag, but I can use Text='<%# Eval("Phone.Number") %>' in the asp:Datalist. Do I need a similiar wrapper for jqgrid.

Comment: I don't use commercial version of jqSuite/jqGrid myself, so I can't help you in the described problem.

Comment: switched to an ObjectDataSource - so get the phone number when the object is created.